# Add an empty json string(array to json) to json file using php

Tags: php, arrays, json

I read a lot of other SO questions before asking this question.

I am going to create a json file with two elements with one element will have array values where as other element should be an empty json string.

I tried the below 2 types of code but the desired output is not coming.

```
$initial_data = array();
$initial_data["names"] = array();
$initial_data["ages"] = json_encode('');
$file_initial_data = json_encode($initial_data);
file_put_contents($t_file_name.'.json',$file_initial_data);
```

The above code is coming like below.

> {"names":[],"ages":"\"\""}

```
$initial_data = array();
$initial_data["names"] = array();
$initial_data["ages"] = '';
$file_initial_data = json_encode($initial_data);
file_put_contents($t_file_name.'.json',$file_initial_data);
```

> {"names":[],"ages":""}

But I need the below output.

> {"names":[],"ages":{}}

Comment: Downvoters please explain. If you found a previous similar question I am happy to know that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in json string `[]` refers blank array and `{}` refers blank object.

have a look on below code:

```
$initial_data = array();
$initial_data["names"] = array();
$initial_data["ages"] = new StdClass();
echo $file_initial_data = json_encode($initial_data);
```

**output**

```
{"names":[],"ages":{}}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I can't find a similar question in SO.